# Select option doesn't load correctly while trying to edit a modal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-select

I'm having this problem when I try to edit from a table and get the values to a modal form, everything works but sometimes the option values doesn't load.

This is the part of the code that i used to get the values and load them

```
$("#nombrePlazaUS > option[value=" + idLocacion + "]").attr("selected", true);
$("#nombreTipoUS > option[value=" + idTipoUser + "]").attr("selected", true);
$("#descripcionUS > option[value=" + idtipodePersona + "]").attr("selected", true);
```

And in the HTML you can see that I used the `value="0"` as the default value:

```
<div class="labelModal">
    <label>Locacion</label>
    <select id="nombrePlazaUS" name="nombrePlazaUS">
        <option value="0" selected>Seleccione la locacion</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="labelModal">
    <label>Tipo de Empleado</label>
    <select id="nombreTipoUS" name="nombreTipoUS">
        <option value="0" selected>Seleccione el tipo de usuario</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="labelModal">
    <label>Tipo de usuario</label>
    <select id="descripcionUS" name="descripcionUS">
        <option value="0" selected>Seleccione el tipo de empleado</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

[Sometimes works like it should](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UE9Yg.png)

But half of the time values doesn't load correctly, everything can be correct or sometime 1 or 2 or even the 3 values doesn't load, totally random but when they load, is the correct value.

[In this case 2 of the values didn't load and they have the default value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tjDb.png)

Comment: The HTML `option`s you are selecting do not exist in the HTML you've show.  So I guess you are dynamically adding them.  Where is that code, and when does it run in relation to the code which then selects an `option`?  When the select fails, have you verified that the HTML `option`s were really added at all?  Please try to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You should deselect all other options using
`.attr("selected", false);` before you select the one.